# Python take result from one class method and input it into another class method

Tags: python, oop

**This question is for learning purposes, it serves little practical uses.**

`TextStat` is a class that has a method `count_words`  that reads a text file and gives words frequency (word counts) dictionary sorted from most frequent word to the least one.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

class TextStat:
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.file_path = file_path
    
    def count_words(self):
        with open(self.file_path, encoding='utf-8') as file:
            text = [line.split() for line in file.readlines()]
            text = list(chain(*text))
            dict_text = dict(Counter(text))
            dict_text = dict(sorted(dict_text.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))
        return dict_text
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```
text_1 = TextStat('path/to/file')
dict_1 = text_1.count_words()
```

**QUESTION**

How could we improve this class by giving it another method `dict_to_df` that takes the output dictionary from `count_words` method without directly calling the `count_words`; so we get a pandas Dataframe if we want to.

```
def dict_to_df(dic):
    '''Given a dictionary; give a pandas Dataframe.'''
    df = pd.DataFrame(data={'WORD': dic.keys(), 'FREQ': dic.values()})
    return df
```

I mean the user should be able to do the following without calling the `text_1.count_words()`:

```
df1 = text_1.dict_to_df(dict_1)
```

`dict_1` should be created inside the class without the user interfering in creating it.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Where did they get `dict_1` if they didn't call `count_words`. You can also just define a method that does straight from a `TextStat` instance to a data frame by calling `count_words` itself.

Comment: @chpner The class should have two methods; one gives us a dictionary ```dict_1```, and another gives us pandas DataFrame... however, the pandas Dataframe cannot be created without a dictionary, but the creation of the dictionary should be done by the class, not the user.

Comment: I'm not clear either. Why wouldn't you just make dict_to_df another method within class TextStat with signature `dict_to_df(self)`.  Then it can call count_words itself to generate the dictionary.  Then the user would just use: `df1 = text_1.dict_to_df()`

Comment: @DarrylG, your answer seems legit, I didn't think about it, being a beginner in python and oop!

Comment: @AkbarHussein--glad It was useful.  Do you see how to make the method dict_to_df?

Comment: @DarrylG I am not sure how to do it, you could post an answer.. I assume it's not difficult.

Comment: @AkbarHussein--posted an answer using your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

Reusing OP code as much as possible

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

class TextStat:
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.file_path = file_path
    
    def count_words(self):
        with open(self.file_path, encoding='utf-8') as file:
            text = [line.split() for line in file.readlines()]
            text = list(chain(*text))
            dict_text = dict(Counter(text))
            dict_text = dict(sorted(dict_text.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))
        return dict_text
    
    def dict_to_df(self):
        dic = self.count_words()  # self refers to object instance and we 
                                  # gain access to its methods
        df = pd.DataFrame(data={'WORD': dic.keys(), 'FREQ': dic.values()}) # using your method
        return df
```

**Usage**

```
text_1 = TextStat('path/to/file')
dict_1 = text_1.count_words()            # As dictionary
df1 = text_1.dict_to_df()                # As DataFrame
```